# SPWeb.ParserEnabled 

Tags: spweb, 2007

What does the SPWeb.ParserEnabled property do?

I had a problem for some document which are not able to update metadata.If i use

ParserEnabled = false.it is working fine for me.

if i use ParserEnabled  property , is there version or other problem for the site.?

Please let me know clearly about ParserEnabled property in details.

thanks 
shiva reddy.p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an Office document is added to a document library, it is parsed for metadata. This option allows you to enable/disable it.

Office 2007 files might have some weird behaviour when trapping ItemAdding, so sometimes you have to disable it in order to update metadata in code.

Answer (score 2):

The Parser Enabled property is responsible to keep the document and list metada in sync. 
So if this is true and you update either the document metadata or list metadata you would notice the change back'n'forth.

If you set it to false then you will find trouble in searching the documents on SharePoint as the serach is metadata based. Moreover setting it to false will either outdate the existing document metadata or wont add any metadata to newly uploaded documents.